# Database 'MyDb' is being recovered. Waiting until recovery is finished

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, recovery

I got so error:

> Database 'MyDb' is being recovered. Waiting until recovery is
>   finished.

I have had a critical operation at that time.

What is the cause of this situation? And how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Crash recovery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.02.logging.aspx) is running on 'MyDb'. Possible causes:

- The SQL Server service was restarted manually, due to a crash or a server stop/start.
- A severe error in the database caused the database to be shut down and recovered.
- Recovery was initiated deliberately by someone executing a RESTORE WITH RECOVERY.
- The [Auto-Close option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249.aspx) is set, causing the database to shut down when the last user exits and run recovery to restart when the next connects.

If recovery is taking a long time to complete and there doesn't appear to be any activity you may need to restore from backups. If you're feeling brave you should start reading everything you can find about [repairing/recovering suspect databases](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/TechEd-Demo-Creating-detaching-re-attaching-and-fixing-a-suspect-database.aspx).

More information on what happened before the database ended up in this state would make for better answers e.g. what actions you carried out, what errors are in the SQL error log etc.

Comment: You'll definitely want to [turn auto close off, for good, everywhere](http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/practical-sql-server-45/sql-server-2008-r2/worst-practice-allowing-autoclose-sql-server-databases-140493).